# brew install v8 not working

Tags: svn, homebrew, v8

I doubt this has to do with my os (OSX) but after running `brew update && brew doctor` I tried to run `brew install v8`

```
xerox:rewardsummit-rails home$ brew install v8
==> Downloading https://github.com/v8/v8/archive/3.25.30.tar.gz     Already downloaded:     /Library/Caches/Homebrew/v8-3.25.30.tar.gz
==> Patching
==> Cloning http://gyp.googlecode.com/svn/trunk
Updating /Library/Caches/Homebrew/v8--gyp--svn
svn: E175002: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://gyp.googlecode.com/svn/trunk'
svn: E175002: OPTIONS of 'http://gyp.googlecode.com/svn/trunk': Could not read status line:     connection was closed by server (http://gyp.googlecode.com)
Error: Failed to download resource "v8--gyp"
Failure while executing: svn up -q --force /Library/Caches/Homebrew/v8--gyp--svn -r 1831
```

I know nothing about SVN.

Comment: Intermittent network glitch? Did you try again?